# Fractured Memory Pages during Memory Allocation?

Tags: c++, linux, memory, memory-management

My current situation is the following: I am allocating `t`bytes with `malloc(t)` then I fill this memory with data (just to force the mapping from virtual to physical memory). The memory page size is 4kB.

Given this situation, I have the following questions:

1.) How much physical memory is used by this (I see the following options):

- exactly `t`bytes no wasted memory (not even a partial memory page)
- `t`B + at most 4kB (one memory page of waste it can be used within the same process).
- `t`B + at most 4kB (one memory page of waste it cannot be used while the allocation exists)
- potentially more than one page of waste due to the mapping technique (some power of 2 magic or blocks of pages... other reasons)

2.) Will this continous piece of virtual memory (one allocation) also be mapped to a continous piece of physical memory?

3.) If there is some waste, can I measure the exact memory footprint of my application? preferably from inside C++.

I should note, that currently my code runs on a ubuntu linux machine, but insights into other systems would still be welcome.

Comment: 2. No. That is one of the ideas behind virtual/paged memory. You may allocate new memory as long as there are enough free physical pages. And it doesn't matter whether they form continuous region in physical address space or are heavily dispersed along it.

Comment: Thanks gudok, I was expecting as much although I thought there might be a policy which encourages "side by side mapping". I think it could be better for current associative caches and prefetchers.

Comment: Is there an unanswered question here? because you haven't closed it

Answer (score 1):

1. - First of all the memory allocations are always rounded (up) to page size.
   - I didn't understand what you said "while allocation exists"...
   - Although it can cause many problems, every thread in your process who has a pointer to the allocated memory can access it (so you need to synchronize those threads etc.
2. You have already got an answer.
3. You can use [mmap](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Memory_002dmapped-I_002fO.html)

Comment: 1. - that seems unreasonably expensive for small allocations (I know they should not be used anyways, but rounding up to 4KB per allocation?)

Comment: While the allocation exists means -- when the allocation is freed its memory will be available again. Why are you talking about concurrency? The question does not mention multiple threads. How can I measure memory usage with mmap?

Comment: I really didn't understabd what you wrote... anyway there are plenty of tools to measure memory usage: mmap, valgrind... depende on your os